# HAML rendering as_json with hash rocket instead of colon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, haml

I'm trying to render a ruby hash to a json string in haml. (the `!` tells haml not to escape the output)

```
! { :name => "Paul" }.as_json
```

I expect this output

```
{ "name":"Paul" }
```

but I get a hash rocket instead of a colon

```
{ "name"=>"Paul" }
```

How do I make haml or `as_json` output a colon instead of a hash rocket for the property/value separator?

Comment: Why don't you just use `to_json` from the Ruby `json` Gem?

Comment: @Linuxios because to_json escapes the quotes which I don't want ({\"name\":\"Paul\"}

Comment: What do yo mean "escapes the quotes"?

Comment: Of course it escapes the quotes! That's how you embed " in a " delimited string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`as_json` is essentially a method that allows you to specify how an object is represented in JSON. It doesn't actually go as far as returning a JSON encoded string. `to_json` is needed for that.

The reason for this is that you might want to decide which fields your model returns when JSON encoded (say, removing the password from the User model), but by using `to_json`, you no longer have the ability to nest that within another JSON object, as it's become an encoded and escaped string.

`to_json` will call `as_json`, and will encode the return value.

Referenced from:
http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/